# Using LIKE in Count(IIF()) in MS Access, get NA count

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013, iif

I'm attempting to get a count of NAs in a field in a table in MS Access. I have multiple NAs:

1. #N/A* (i.e. NAs that start with hash & "N/A" & some more text that varies.)
2. NaN
3. NA
4. N/A

(They all mean something different for us, so it i actually useful to have the different NAs.)

This works for one specific NA, "#N/A N/A":

```
SELECT Count(IIf([Short Int % Eqy Flt] = '#N/A N/A' ,0 )) AS MyTotal
FROM tblFirst250
```

The above returns 141, which seems correct.

This returns 0:

```
SELECT Count(IIf([Short Int % Eqy Flt] LIKE '#N/A' ,0 )) AS MyTotal
FROM tblFirst250
```

The above should return 142 because I have 141 "#N/A N/A" and 1 "#N/A Invalid Security".

Really what I am after is something that counts all of my NAs in the [Short Int % Eqy Flt] field. See my list of NAs above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#` has a special meaning [*Any single digit (0–9)*] when used in a `Like` pattern.  You can tell Access to treat it as just the normal `#` character by putting it inside a character range like this ... `[#]`.

Also, I think you want to match `[#]N/A` followed by additional characters, so tack on a wildcard character to the end of the pattern.

```sql
SELECT Sum(IIf([Short Int % Eqy Flt] LIKE '[#]N/A*', 1, 0)) AS MyTotal
FROM tblFirst250;
```

I used `Sum` instead of `Count`.  But if you prefer `Count` ...

```sql
SELECT Count(IIf([Short Int % Eqy Flt] LIKE '[#]N/A*', 1, Null)) AS MyTotal
FROM tblFirst250;
```

Comment: And this answers the question of getting all of my NAs: SELECT Sum(IIf([Short Int % Eqy Flt] LIKE '[#]N/A*' OR [Short Int % Eqy Flt]  = 'N/A' OR [Short Int % Eqy Flt]  = 'NA' OR [Short Int % Eqy Flt]  = 'NaN', 1, 0)) AS MyTotal
FROM tblFirst250

Comment: I don't know.  If there is a difference, I would guess `Count` as the winner.   Try it both ways and see whether you can even notice a difference.